# Is Workflow Manager "multi-process" / multi-threaded?

Tags: workflow-activity, workflow-manager

I have written a custom code activity in .NET 4.5.1 to be available as a custom workflow step in SP 2013/2016.

I have chosen Serilog as the logging framework I'm going to use to add logging, using the File sink to log to text files on the workflow server.

In the [Serilog File sink instructions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#getting-started), it says

> **Important:** By default, only one process may write to a log file at a given time. See Shared log files below for information on
> multi-process sharing.

and then in the "[Shared log files](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file#shared-log-files)" section, it gives instructions for how to "enable multi-process shared log files".

Is this something I should do for code that is being run by Workflow Manager?  Should Workflow Manager be considered "multi-process"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try written not to file but to use an entry in an SQL table (for example) and check again. In Serilog it's config says: WriteTo => MSSqlServer. Link t
https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver

If you can use Azure. I would advise AppInhsight.
But I also advised looking at other more centralized and specialized solutions such: Loggly ($), ELK.

On my previus projects we not use SP log (ULS, mess) and build centralize and aggregate all logs from all projects, solutions, tips etc.